# FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'shopfavorite' into field :Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using reverse `foreignkey` using django predefine function `prefetch_related`. but i'm getting the error: `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'shopfavorite' into field.` . 
Also i'm getting this error through command line: `AttributeError: Cannot find 'shopfavorite_set' on ShopOwnerShopDetails object, 'shopfavorite_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()` 
What is the exact issue? Any helpful, would be much appreciated. thank you so much in advance.

models :

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # common fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

class ShopOwnerShopDetails(models.Model):
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    shop_location = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ShopFavorite(models.Model):
    shop_id = models.ForeignKey(ShopOwnerShopDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='favorite_shop_id')
    favorited_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_favorite_shop')
```

views :

```
class GarageShopListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        user = request.user

        queryset = ShopOwnerShopDetails.objects.filter(
                shopfavorite__favorited_by=user
                ).prefetch_related('shopfavorite_set',)
        serializer = ShopOwnerShopDetailsSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})
        data = serializer.data
```

Comment: Can you show us your ```User``` class?

Comment: @OliverHnat  I've edited on my question. please look at it.

Comment: well `ShopOwnerShopDetails` doesn't have a FK to User, shouldn't you use `ShopFavorite` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error you get is quite clear: you're trying to access to `shopfavorite_set` from `ShopOwnerShopDetails` and this model doesn't have any FK pointing to User.

If I understand correctly you want to get a list of all favourites shops for the current user.
In this case I'll user a different queryset

```py
queryset = ShopFavorite.objects.filter(
    favorited_by=user
).select_related('favorited_by', 'shop_id')
```

then in the serializer you have access to both `User` and `ShopOwnerShopDetails` instance